# Folder inaccessible, labeled as "file", tried rescanning sd card

Tags: files, emulators

I downloaded MAME4droid and I wanted to put a Galaga ROM on it, but when I tried to find the MAME4all folder it didn't show up in windows. As prescribed, I rescanned the sd card, but all that did was this: [image]

If it matters, my device is a Droid MAXX (not the Razr).

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the best way to fix the problem was to use a file manager app (because there isn't one on the device by default) to move the ROM into the right folder.

Comment: Your question ( __apples__ ) said you couldn't see it on windows. Then your answer( __oranges__ ) states to use a file manager on your device to move it to the correct location...... Your problem then is unclear. Re-edit your question for clarification please, otherwise it might get flagged for being unclear. Also you can comment on your own question.